# JavaScript, Arrow functions

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I am struggling to understand arrow functions on this example:

```
const printArray = function (array) {
  array.forEach(function (element) {
    console.log(element);
  });
};
```

I've been trying sth like:

```
const printArray = array => {
  array.forEach = element => {
    console.log(element)
  }
}
```

However, it wouldn't work.
Can someone clarify me on the example above?

Comment: `array.forEach = element => { console.log(element) }` should be `array.forEach(element => { console.log(element) } )`

Comment: In one you're *calling* `forEach`, in the other you're *assigning* to it.

Comment: `forEach` method takes a callback function as an argument. You are not passing that argument to `forEach`. You are assigning an arrow function to `array.forEach`. To make the second code example work, replace the callback function with an arrow function by removing the `function` keyword and adding an arrow between parameter list and opening curly bracket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way

```
const printArray = array => {
  array.forEach(element => {
    console.log(element);
  });
};
```

`function(a) {}` is replaced by `a => {}`
`function(b) {return x}` is replaced by `b => x`
`function(c,d) {}` is replaced by `(c,d) => {}`

`forEach()` is a function *call*, not a function *definition*. Only the definitions are written with the array function expression.

For further information look here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Steps to convert a traditional function expression to an arrow function expression

```
function (a) {
  return a + 100;
}

// 'Replace' `function` with `=>`

(a) => {
  return a + 100;
}

// If function body consists of only a return statement

(a) => a + 100;

// If function only has one parameter

a => a + 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const printArray = (array) => {
  array.forEach(element  => {
    console.log(element);
  });
};
```

This should be the correct syntax :)

Answer (score 0):

Just reduce it to

```js
const printArray = array => {
  array.forEach(console.log);
};
```